Reading items from array returns as string
When I try to read individual strings from the array, it returns as a string.
[string[]]$csProjectFolders = @()
        
function GetAllProjectFolders ($folderPath) {
    # Get *.csproj files in the current folder
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -File -Recurse -Filter *.csproj
    
    # If any .csproj files are found, add the parent folder to the array
    if ($files.Count -gt 0) {
        foreach ($file in $files) {
            $folderName = Split-Path -Path $file.FullName -Parent
            $csProjectFolders += $folderName            
        }
        
        return $csProjectFolders
    }          
}


$csProjectFolders = GetAllProjectFolders($PSScriptRoot)
foreach ($folder in $csProjectFolders) {    
    Write-Host $folder    
}

Output:

What am I doing wrong here

Is there something in your code you're not showing us? With your current code $csProjectFolders is a string collection not a single string. Also could be simplified to just $csProjectFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File -Recurse -Filter *.csproj | Split-Path -Parent there is no need to manually add items to an array when powershell can do it for you

@SantiagoSquarzon Tried your suggestion and updated my question. Could you please have a look. Thank you.

there is no .FullName property for each $folder those are already strings :) // Split-Path -Parent outputs a string

@SantiagoSquarzon Tried that too which returns empty string.

You are causing this problem with the unnecessary casting, array initialization, and collection. Just let the pipeline handle your output for you.
function GetAllProjectFolders ($folderPath) {
    # Get *.csproj files in the current folder
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -File -Recurse -Filter *.csproj

    # For all csproj files found, output the parent folder on the pipeline 
    if ($files.Count -gt 0) {
        foreach ($file in $files) {
            Split-Path -Path $file.FullName -Parent          
        }
    }          
}


$csProjectFolders = GetAllProjectFolders $PSScriptRoot

foreach ($folder in $csProjectFolders) {    
    Write-Host $folder    
}

Also, you don't pass arguments to functions in powershell with the parenthesis.
You can do it as shown, where it's positionally specified
GetAllProjectFolders $PSScriptRoot

For scripts, it's preferred to be explicit with named parameters
GetAllProjectFolders -folderpath $PSScriptRoot


Sorry, did not understand the statement in the first foreach. It is splitting but where is it saving the result?

It is not saving it anywhere. The function outputs the paths. You collect the paths with the variable $csProjectFolders from the function call

@sukesh, you might want to read: Why should I avoid using the increase assignment operator (+=) to create a collection
